# Conditions on a rate of change of a continuous function to be bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, bounds-of-integration

Suppose  $f(s)$  is continuous on  $[0,\infty)$  and  $\lim_{s\to \infty} f(s) =1$. How fast should it decrease to $1$ so that $$F(t)=\int_0^t f(s)\sin(s)ds$$ to be bounded? In what cases it is unbounded?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: I have an idea of using integration by parts and trying to estimate the new integral involving derivative $f'(s)$ and $cos(s)$. Still not clear what to do next.

Comment: Since we aren't given that $f$ is differentiable, that won't work.

Comment: Another approach is to rewrite the expression $f(s)\sin(s)=(f(s)-1+1)\sin(s)$. There will be two integrals, one of which is $(f(s)-1))\sin(s)$. If the function $f(s)-1$ decreases monotonously, then the integral converges by Dirichlet's test.